# Android marshmallow Notification issue

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-6.0-marshmallow, illegalargumentexception

My following code on generating the notification works well on Android 3.x, 4.x and 5.x.

```
    this.builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setSmallIcon(iconId)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
            .setContentText(message);
    this.builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

However I got the following exception when I launch it on a Android 6.x device.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid notification (no valid small icon): Notification(pri=2 contentView=[appname]/0x1090085 vibrate=default sound=null defaults=0x6 flags=0x11 color=0x00000000 category=msg vis=PRIVATE)

I have already included notification icons with size 
25 x 25, 38 x 38, 50 x 50 and 75 x 75 in my drawable folders.

The code works perfectly before, just crashed the app with the exception on marshmallow.

Can any one help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The sizes of your icons look incorrect, and this might be the reason the system complains. Check the correct sizes in [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html#size11) and fix the icons.

Comment: The icon set are generated in Android Studio 
File > New > Image Assets > Notification Icons

And that's why have such size... I suppose generated from Android Studio means that the size are correct?

Comment: The same exception still here even i have turned those icons to size 24, 36 and 48...

Answer (score 0):

You to add runtime permission for marshmallow

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Permission for what?

Comment: Why need to add permission and what kind of permission to be added?

Comment: Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY

Comment: Still the same exception even with the permission set.

Comment: Please check this link http://www.gdomc.com/0501/push-notification-issue-in-android-marshmallow-and-lollipop/

Comment: Issue is getting because of small icon method

Comment: Ratnesh, I know that the problem is at the smallIcon. However, i do not know how to solve it. The icons are generated by the studio, supposed to be correct in format, isn't it? It is just the default icons generated from Android studio.

Comment: Hey please go through this link http://www.gdomc.com/0501/push-notification-issue-in-android-marshmallow-and-lollipop/